# Why do we need a database like MySql and MongoDB for our data?

Tags: mysql, database, mongodb, storage

I know the difference between the two databases. Relational and Non. What I am getting at is why can't we just keep all the files on the server. The server in itself can be a database and as long as you keep a clean organized folder structure, what is the need to use a database to store you data. I mean a database like MySql is essentially a spreadsheet. So what is their primary use, how is using one make storing your information easier?

Comment: It's certainly possible, but it starts to break down when you've got millions/billions of rows. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flat-file_database Things like MySQL are *far* more powerful than a simple spreadsheet under the hood, with things like indexing permitting fast queries against large amounts of data.

Comment: You can definitely just store your data in plain files on your server. It really depends on what you are doing with the data. A database becomes incredibly useful once you need to perform queries your data, i.e., find me all records matching these conditions. While it's still possible to do that sort of thing with plain files, databases are designed specifically for such tasks, and will almost certainly be orders of magnitude faster once you are dealing with large amounts of data.

Comment: Say you need to store information about clients, projects, and invoices. Using your system, how can you simultaneously see all invoices belonging to the same client, and all invoices for projects completed this year? With a database, this is trivial.

Answer (score 0):

Agree, simply a server with storage is enough for keeping the data. But, these DB Software helps you on RETRIEVAL of DATA (Very FASTER., that too in ultra low latency) which you can't achieve by simplying keeping it organized structure. It needs more data engineering, which are applied on these Relational and NON-R DBs.